# How do I join two separate objects so I can edit them as one mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created two meshes as separate objects and I want to create a face joining them. However, since they are two different objects, I can not edit them to add the face.

Is it possible to join them into one mesh?

Comment: This question is better than the one which it's a duplicate of. Any way to reverse the "Duplicate" process?

Answer (score 9):

### How to join two meshes with the *Join* command

It is very easy to join two meshes together using the [*Join*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects) (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) command so that you can add a face between them.

Here is how you do it: Select both meshes at the same time, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

Now both meshes are one object and in Edit mode, you can add a face between them.