# How do you resurface these objects into one object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

This question looked as if it were the answer, but when I tried to follow the answer, I didn't get the expected result.
[How do I join two separate objects so I can edit them as one mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/how-do-i-join-two-separate-objects-so-i-can-edit-them-as-one-mesh)

Here is what happened.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2aijftpztba4li/tori.blend?dl=0

My next step was to mark the inner vertices of the torii and add another face, and also add a face to the ends.  Would I have to then have to manually delete the interior parts of the object to create a manifold?

Comment: If I had attempted to create the face for each vertex, I expect that  might work.  So is that the answer, or do it with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the effect you're looking to achieve

[image]

the way I managed it using the blend file you uploaded to dropbox was:

1) [if not already activated,] activate the Mesh:LoopTools addon by means of User Preferences > Addons > Mesh:LoopTools;

2) delete the outer edges joining the two torii in your blend file;

3) Select the each of the edge loops you did on the two torii by deselecting all vertices <kbd>A key</kbd>, followed by selecting the same edge loop you had selected on one torus, holding the shift key and selecting the same edge loop you had on the other torus; and

4) In the Edges menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E key</kbd>) choosing the "Bridge Edge Loops" option.

Caveats

As the screenshot shows, I performed these steps in 2.71. My memory on this is just a bit hazy, but it seems to me that up until some version of Blender (2.6?) the Mesh:LoopTools Addon may not have been included in the distribution, and you may need to find it and install it from the Blender Addons repository.

Your two torii seem to have the same number of segments; if the two torii do not have the same number of segments the results may not be shown as here, and you may need to adjust the results differently.

In order for this method to work, the two meshes you want to join need to be part of the same object. If you add the second torus to the first as a different object, the two torii need to be combined into the same object as in the method set out in the other question you cited, and then the expanded object manipulated in edit mode.

Comment: Note: The steps appear to work even if the number of segments aren't the same.

Comment: It depends upon how you define "work". While testing my answer, on one instance I omitted a segment of edge loop in one torus; when I performed the bridge operation, I did get a bridge, but it would have required significant manual "beautifying of the segments..

Comment: Agreed.  Results are not guaranteed if the number of segments aren't the same.  Thus far, I haven't figured out when it will fail.