# How do I combine mesh layers?

Tags: workflow

How do I combine one mesh layer into another mesh layer in Blender version 2.81a?

I  do not know the command to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you mean joining objects? If so, then read this question: [How do I join two separate objects so I can edit them as one mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/how-do-i-join-two-separate-objects-so-i-can-edit-them-as-one-mesh)

Comment: Got it. Typed ctrl+J and it worked. Learning the basics. So far so good. Thankyou for your help